# SUM return wrong value when join 3 table - MS SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 3 table need to join namely table **invoice**, **items** and **payments**. The table **items** and **payments** will join to the table **Invoice** based on **invoice id**

Now I need to get **SUM** of **sales, sales after cost** and **payment** by invoice date.

So this is my query

```
SELECT SUM((I.price * qty) - (I.price * qty * discount)) as totalSales,SUM((I.price * qty) - (I.price * qty * discount)-costItem) as salesAfterCost, SUM(PAY.amount) as paymentReceived
FROM tbl_inv B LEFT JOIN tbl_item I ON B.id = I.id_invoice 
LEFT JOIN tbl_payment PAY ON B.id = PAY.id_invoice
WHERE B.dateInv = '2013-04-01'
GROUP BY B.id,b.dateInv;
```

And the result will return like this

```
totalSales  salesAfterCost  paymentReceived
 75.540000    67.540000        622.8000
```

But when I check with this query to get **total payment**, it will return with different value.

```
SELECT SUM(PAY.amount) paymentReceived
FROM tbl_inv B LEFT JOIN tbl_payment PAY ON B.id = PAY.id_invoice
WHERE B.dateInv = '2013-04-01';
```

Result :

```
paymentReceived
155.7000
```

And query for **sales**

```
SELECT SUM((I.price * qty) - (I.price * qty * discount)) as totalSales,SUM((I.price * qty) - (I.price * qty * discount)-costItem) as salesAfterCost
FROM tbl_inv B LEFT JOIN tbl_item I ON B.id = I.id_invoice
WHERE B.dateInv = '2013-04-01';
```

Result :

```
totalSales  salesAfterCost
37.770000   33.770000
```

How can I resolved this thing?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is right. But it could also be resolved if you can join a payment to a specific item on an invoice.

Comment: @davmos - given that payments are being multiplied by 4, and sales by 2, I don't think that there's a 1-1 correspondence between invoices and payments.

Comment: Sure @Damien_The_Unbeliever, but I didn't say that. I just hinted at the possibility of a 1-1 relationship between **an item** on an invoice and a payment. Probably not possible, but thought I'd throw it into the mix to aid understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `SUM()`s into subqueries - at the moment, every row from payment is being matched against every row from invoice, resulting in a cartesian join

```
SELECT I.totalSales,I.salesAfterCost, PAY.paymentReceived
FROM tbl_inv B
LEFT JOIN (
   select id_invoice,SUM((I.price * qty) - (I.price * qty * discount)) as totalSales,
       SUM((I.price * qty) - (I.price * qty * discount)-costItem) as salesAfterCost
  from tbl_item group by id_invoice) I
      ON
         B.id = I.id_invoice 
LEFT JOIN (
    select id_invoice,SUM(amount) as paymentReceived
    from tbl_payment group by id_invoice) PAY
       ON
         B.id = PAY.id_invoice
WHERE B.dateInv = '2013-04-01'
```